# Extend a SPAN, placed after other elements, to right border of its container

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 2 columns. In each one is present a simple text and another sentence wrapped in a SPAN.
Table columns have fixed width and obviously texts are completely random length. I would like to "extend" span width to right margin of cell table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>Text 1 <span>other text 1</span></td>
      <td>Text 2 <span>other text 2</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and css rules:

```
td
{
    border:solid 1px black;
    padding:5px;
    width:200px;
}

span
{
    border-bottom:dotted 1px red;
}
```

Here a JSFiddle [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/F8Pyp/).

As you can see, dotted red border under SPAN is only under text... I would like to extend it until right margin of each cell, so I'm looking for a way to extend span length from its initial position (dependent by preceding black text) to right margin of container.

Is it possible in some ways?

Answer (score 1):

`spans` are inline elements. To do what you want to do, you would need to turn it into a block element. At that point, You would need to use either `inline-block` and widths or block and floats.

You can use JS to do this however:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var containerWidth = $('table td').width();
  var textWidth = $('span:first-child').width();
  var newWidth = containerWidth - textWidth;
  $('span.second').css('width',newWidth);
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyJFA

Comment: Unfortunately is not what I need.... as you said, first sentence could be arbitrary long... and SPAN/DIV content should not go on another row, but simply be shorter.....

Comment: There is a way to do this with JS if you wanted to - essentially get the width of the container, the width of the first span, then subtract the difference and apply that width to the second.

Comment: I'm sorry... :-( but, again, it's not the solution that I'm looking for.... I just updated my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8Pyp/5/)  to display what I need.
Obviously this solution is STATIC and not auto-adaptive, but the final look is what I need.

Is it possible to obtain it automatically in a such way? Thank you.

Comment: I've updated mine to include the JS you would need. use `jQuery each` to go through each container and apply.

Answer (score 0):

Change `span` to `div` as `span` is an inline element whie `div` is block element.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>Text 1 <div class="try">Other text 1</div></td>
      <td>Text 2 <div class="try"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table 
{ 
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
td
{
    border:solid 1px black;
    padding:5px;
    width:200px;
}
.try
{
    border-bottom:dotted 1px red;
    width: 150px;
    height: 15px;
    float: right;
}
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/F8Pyp/4/)